# If I change the html src to data-src, the image is not output

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend

I changed the `image tag` `src` to `data-src` .
However, `src` is output normally, but if you change it to `data-src`, The image is not visible in the browser.

```
import GooglePlayImages from '../../assets/img/googleplay.png'

const Home = () => {
   return  (
       <>
      <img data-src={GooglePlayImages} alt="google-play" />
       </>
)

export default Home
```

why is there no output?

Answer (score 0):

[Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

> `data-*` attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on DOM.

`data-src` is often used to store image links for lazy image loading. The link value of `data-src` will not send an HTTP get request to the resource remote server, but `src` does.

When the picture appears in the viewport area, we will use the JS script to assign the links on the `data-src` to `src`.

Comment: So is it saved in dataset.src?

Comment: @minsu Sorry. I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you put an image with `data-src` , isn't the value stored as an array in dataset.src ?

Comment: @minsu You can get the data via `el.dataset.src`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset